# add custom csv upload field in System.xml file

Tags: magento2

Hi i have created a custom module and added a custom file upload link

Here is the output image

[image]

**System.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="test" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>
                Test
            </label>
        </tab>
        <section id="zipcode" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="120" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Zipcode</label>
            <tab>test</tab>
            <resource>Learn_Module::config_module</resource>
            <group id="config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Check delivery postcode</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="postcodes" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Postcodes</label>
                    <comment>Comma-separated</comment>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>


                <!-- csv file upload starts here -->
                <field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                 <label>Upload Csv File</label>
                 <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>
                 <upload_dir>pub/media/myupload</upload_dir>
                </field>
                <!-- file upload ends here -->

                <field id="success_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="21" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Success message</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
                <field id="error_message" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="22" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Error message</label>
                    <depends><field id="enable">1</field></depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

Now i want to upload csv file of zipcodes but am not totaly sure how to upload it can anyone please help me

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please accept my answer by clicking on the right sign below score of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the easiest if you add a custom backend model (for example **Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Backend\Zipcode**) to the config field in the system.xml file. Then use the **afterSave()** to save whatever you want.

Note: Your backend model class should extend **\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value** class.

You can have a look at the following files for reference:

- /vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Config/Backend/Tablerate.php
- /vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml